# Progress indication with HTTP file download using WinHTTP

Tags: c++, winhttp, winhttprequest

I want to implement an progress bar in my C++ windows application when downloading a file using WinHTTP.  Any idea how to do this?  It looks as though the WinHttpSetStatusCallback is what I want to use, but I don't see what notification to look for... or how to get the "percent downloaded"...

Help!

Thanks!

Comment: You could increment your progress bar in the Do while loop (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384270(VS.85).aspx#Downloading_resource)

Comment: Yeah, this is actually what I ended up doing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383917(VS.85).aspx):

`WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_DATA_AVAILABLE`

> Data is available to be retrieved with
>   WinHttpReadData. The
>   lpvStatusInformation parameter points
>   to a DWORD that contains the number of
>   bytes of data available. The
>   dwStatusInformationLength parameter
>   itself is 4 (the size of a DWORD).

and

`WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_READ_COMPLETE`

> Data was successfully read from the
>   server. The lpvStatusInformation
>   parameter contains a pointer to the
>   buffer specified in the call to
>   WinHttpReadData. The
>   dwStatusInformationLength parameter
>   contains the number of bytes read.

There may be other relevant notifications, but these two seem to be the key ones. Getting "percent" is not necessarily trivial because you may not know how much data you're getting (not all downloads have content-length set...); you can get the headers with:

`WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HEADERS_AVAILABLE`

> The response header has been received
>   and is available with
>   WinHttpQueryHeaders. The
>   lpvStatusInformation parameter is
>   NULL.

and if Content-Length IS available then the percentage can be computed by keeping track of the total number of bytes at each "data available" notification, otherwise your guess is as good as mine;-).